# In git how to find out which files were added after a specific tag?

Tags: git, database-migration, flyway, git-tag

I maintain database migration sql script files.

I tag my commits with git tag.

Suppose I have tags like 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3

**I only  want to modify a (DB migration sql script) file when no tag was added to repo after that file was created. How can I find this out?**

If the file was created and then a (version) tag was added then I dont want to modify that sql migration script, instead I will add a totally new sql file which helps me do what I want.

Comment: So, basically, you want to see the list of files added since the last tag, correct?

Comment: @user494461 I notice you've added a bounty. Could you clarify your question to indicate what you're looking for and why the existing answer doesn't cover it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use git diff with some grepping as follows:

`git diff --name-status your-tag..HEAD | grep ^A`

This means:

"get me the differences between `your-tag` and `HEAD`, showing the file name and its status (added, modified, deleted, created). "

The grep then filters it to files that have been added, which `--name-status` indicates by beginning the line with an uppercase "A".

Answer (score 2):

To automatically find the latest tag, you can use the following command:

```
git describe $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)
```

Then, the [diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) command will give you a list of added files between two commits:

```
git diff --diff-filter=A --name-only $start_commit_id $end_commit_id
```

More options can be added to the diff filter, for instance `--diff-filter=AR` will list the files that have been [A]dded plus [R]enamed.
Now if you put both commands together, you will get the list of files since the last tag, regardless what the last tag label is:

```
git diff --diff-filter=A --name-only $(git describe
     $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)) HEAD
```